# Onclick event controlled by span text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where I want the outcome of the click to depend on the text of a span tag but. It runs the first function but then when that function changes the text of the span and it is click again it just runs the first function again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#updetails").click(function () {
        var udetails = $("#updetails").text();
        if (udetails = "Update Details") {
            updatemandetails();
            return;
        }
        if (udetails = "Submit Details") {
            subupdetails();
            return;
        }        
    });    
});
function updatemandetails() {
alert("Update Details");
$("#updetails").text("Submit Details");}


function subupdetails(){
alert("submit details");
$("#updetails").text("Update Details");}
```

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `==` or `===`, You are simply assigning the values.

```
if (udetails === "Update Details") {
```

Full code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#updetails").click(function () {
    var udetails = $("#updetails").text();
    if (udetails === "Update Details") {
        updatemandetails();
        return;
    }
    if (udetails === "Submit Details") {
        subupdetails();
        return;
    }        
  });
});
```

Comment: @rbradshaw Glad to help.. Consider this answer as accepted if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant to use "==" instead of "=" in the if condition